# Jquery autocomplete change event not firing

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm using JQuery UI autocomplete feature and I'm facing a problem.

This is my code:

```
   $("#Id").autocomplete({
      source: url,
          change : function (event,ui){
    alert('changed');       
    }
});
```

I would like that the change event will fire any time the user type anything in the input text

It's not the case here.

when I type something it does not fire until I'm pressing with the mouse on somewhere else on the screen.

How to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem by using the keypress event separately. instead of using the change event.

The new code:

```
$("#Id").autocomplete({
  source: url
});    

$("#Id").keydown(function() {
    // Logic goes here
});
```

This problem occurred because we got out of focus two events were fired the onBlur and the onclick event of some button I have. and this cause inconsistently behavior.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to bind a keypress event to it directly?

```
   $("#Id").autocomplete({
      source: url,
          change : function (event,ui){
    alert('changed');       
    }
});    

$("#Id").bind('keypress',function(){$(this).autocomplete.change});
```

Comment: I tested it and it does not working.

This is my entire code

$("#Id").autocomplete({
  autoFocus: true,
  minLength: 0,
  source: url,
  select:  function (event, ui) {
   alert('select');
  },
  change : function (event,ui){
   alert('changed');
  }
 });
 
$("#Id").bind('keypress',function(){$(this).autocomplete.change});